# Generating NSAttributedString with NSHTMLTextDocumentType crash the app

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsattributedstring

We need to use NSHTMLTextDocumentType in a UITextView to display some rich text

We implemented the new method in main thread and we are getting random errors in each run of the application. All the errors are the same kind of error, but with some small differences:

Error 1:

> -[__NSCFString myView]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x175a1a10
>   *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString myView]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x175a1a10'

Error 2:

> -[NSObservationSource myView]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x165ec0b0
>   Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException'

Error 3:

> -[__NSSetM myView]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1469aba0
>   Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException'

Error 4:

> +[CATransaction synchronize] called within transaction
>
> -[CALayer myView]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17ed7ae0
>   Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[CALayer myView]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17ed7ae0'
>   *** First throw call stack:> -[CALayer myView]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x165ca180

Error 5:

> -[**NSMallocBlock** myView]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x16eb6d00
>
> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[**NSMallocBlock** myView]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x16eb6d00'

Error 6:

> -[_NSObserverList myView]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17573700
>
> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_NSObserverList myView]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17573700'

### What we use:

```
- (NSAttributedString *)attributedStringWithHTML:(NSString *)HTML {
    NSDictionary *options = @{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType };
    return [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[HTML dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:options documentAttributes:NULL error:NULL];
}
```

#### Related links

Generating NSAttributedString from HTML
https://github.com/codepath/objc_ios_guides/wiki/Generating-NSAttributedString-from-HTML
Why NSAttributedString import html must be on main thread?
http://www.cnblogs.com/ioriwellings/p/3556990.html

Comment: The error is related to a method or property `myView` which must be somewhere else because it's not in the code you've posted.

Comment: The error is only produced  if we use `attributedStringWithHTML`. if i delete these two lines of code and i use  simple nsstring, there is no error. So i don't know why all the exceptions are mentioning MyView class, as it is simply the view in which is contained the UITextView which is containing the rich text. MyView is a UIView class

Comment: Update your question with a relevant stack trace from the crash and point out the actual exact line of code causing the crash based on the stack trace.

Comment: Turn on NSZombies and it should be able to tell you which deallocated instance of your view you are calling methods on